# i have downloaded and tar ed Ruby 1.9.2 package. how to install it now?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

i have downloaded and tar ed Ruby 1.9.2 package. how to install it now ?? i am working on ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vague question, and you should probably pull up a tutorial to walk you through the process if you're not sure how to do this yet, but…

```
tar -xzf ruby_1.9.2.tar.gz
cd ruby_1.9.2/
./configure
make && make install
```

Might I suggest using RVM instead? It'll handle installing ruby, and let you manage and switch between different rubies and gem sets for each application. It's really easy to get started with, too. Check it out:

http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/

Comment: Encapsulate code or command line errors in backticks (`) so that we can see them highlighted and your question text doesn't blend into them. If it says "Error" then I would have to say that there was an error. That doesn't surprise me, since you'll need to satisfy a lot of dependencies in order to install Ruby and you're trying to do it all manually. Try using RVM instead.

Answer (score 1):

if you are on ubuntu, you can use apt to install ruby1.9.2

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full
```

check your install

```
ruby1.9.1 -v
```

it will return ruby 1.9.2-p0.

edit your .bashrc , back to normal.

```
alias ruby="ruby1.9.1"
alias irb="irb1.9.1"
alias gem="gem1.9.1"
```

everything will be allright.

Comment: I just love how they do that. 1.9.1 is 1.9.2. Sigh.

Comment: Question: What happens if you're trying to access `/usr/bin/ruby`? Will the `ruby` get mangled to `ruby1.9.1` because it's been aliased?

Comment: @the Tin Man: that's the version numbering scheme ruby-core came up with. There's really not much Debian can do about it.